# jQuery - action only when there is no text-indent

Tags: jquery

I have a code for getting position of first letter of an element, although it doesn't work when I have some text-indent set (for example when I need only an icon without text in ) I've tried to modify my function like this, in order to add 's only to elements with no text-indent:

```
    $.fn.inlineOffset = function (){
    if ($(this).css('text-indent') == '0px') {
    var el = $('<i/>').css('display', 'inline').insertBefore(this[0]);
        pos = el.offset();
    el.remove();
    return pos;
  }};
```

But somehow it doesn't work. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to work this out.

Comment: `.css()` only gets inline style attributes, not styles inherited from CSS files. Where are you setting the text-indent property?

Comment: My problem is that I want it to work for items that has no text-indent set, but I dont know how to write this in if statement.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `if ($(this).css('text-indent') === undefined)`

Comment: No, because it's returning false. If I type in console $('.class').css('text-indent') it returns 0px

Comment: Check for either of them with `||`.

Comment: I found out, what I've done wrong. I forgot about else statement and It wasn't giving back any position when text-indent != 0px. I must be a little bit distracted... Thanks anyway! Everything works.